# android button is not showing after I put it in a scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

so I had to make a layout where it contains 4 expandables and below those expandables is a imagebutton and below that is 1 edit text and below that is several textviews than 2 imagebuttons on the bottom.

But somehoww those two buttons aren't showing. I'm guessing the issue is with the height, I tried to change the height but still not working.
these are the codes :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nama"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVkonsumsi_user"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVprotein"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVsayur"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVkacang"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

      <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="3" >

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/buttonTambah"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="#393939" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/InputMenuMakanan"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:clickable="false"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Lainnya"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:typeface="normal" />
                            </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_weight="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="4" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="3" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/gram"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:weightSum="8" >

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:weightSum="4" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="Kalori" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/takaranKalori"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="Protein" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/takaranProtein"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:weightSum="4" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="Karbohidrat" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/takaranKarbohidrat"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="Takaran" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/jenisTakaran"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:weightSum="4" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="LemakTotal" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/takaranLemakTotal"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="Makanan" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/namaMakanan"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:weightSum="4" >

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="takaranKolesterol" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/takaranKolesterol"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:text="takaranSodium" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/takaranSodium"
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="3" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="6" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="KaloriTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranKaloriTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="ProteinTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranProteinTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="KarbohidratTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranKarbohidratTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="SodiumTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranSodiumTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="LemakTotalTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranLemakTotalTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="KolesterolTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranKolesterolTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="2" >

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="28.5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="28.5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1" >

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:background="#393939" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/InputMenuMakanan"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:clickable="false"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Cancel"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:typeface="normal" />
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="45dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="28.5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="28.5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1" >

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/buttonDone"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:background="#393939" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/InputMenuMakanan"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:clickable="false"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Next"
                                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:typeface="normal" />
                            </FrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: where are the 2 buttons in your xml???

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nama"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVkonsumsi_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVprotein"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVsayur"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/EVkacang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonTambah"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#393939" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InputMenuMakanan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Lainnya"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_weight="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="4" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="3" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/gram"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:weightSum="8" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Kalori" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranKalori"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Protein" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranProtein"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Karbohidrat" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranKarbohidrat"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Takaran" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/jenisTakaran"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="LemakTotal" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranLemakTotal"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Makanan" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/namaMakanan"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:weightSum="4" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="takaranKolesterol" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranKolesterol"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="takaranSodium" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/takaranSodium"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="3" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="6" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="4" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="KaloriTotal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takaranKaloriTotal"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="ProteinTotal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takaranProteinTotal"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="4" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="KarbohidratTotal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takaranKarbohidratTotal"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="SodiumTotal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takaranSodiumTotal"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="4" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="LemakTotalTotal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takaranLemakTotalTotal"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="KolesterolTotal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/takaranKolesterolTotal"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#393939" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InputMenuMakana"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonDone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#393939" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InputMenuMaka"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Next"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```